# Ошибка записи в Postgres

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, sequelize.js

Такая ситуация. После создания таблиц в БД, сидами добавляю нового пользователя (в конфигурации id = 1).
Все норм отрабатывает, пользователь записан в БД.
Но если я добавляю нового пользователя через приложение, вылетает ошибка "Validation error".
Если пытаюсь еще раз - та же ошибка.
При третьей попытке аккаунт создается, но уже с id = 3.

Поле id инкрементное. В дебаге "спотыкается" о метод **create** (sequelize).

Что это может быть, куда смотреть?

DDL ::

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
    login character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "roleId" integer,
    banned boolean DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT users_email_key UNIQUE (email),
    CONSTRAINT users_login_key UNIQUE (login),
    CONSTRAINT "users_roleId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("roleId")
        REFERENCES public.roles (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: На поле установлен уникальный индекс и в таблице уже есть записи с передаваемым ID. Если бы вы привели текст ошибки целиком, было более понятно, откуда ноги растут. Одно можно сказать сразу, что за уникальность номеров должно ответчать не приложение а сама БД.

Comment: Провел эксперимент, сначала сидом добавил в пустую таблицу пользователя:
{ id: 1, login: 'admin', password: '321' }  


Затем в pgadmin пробую вбить данные нового пользователя, не затрагивая поле id (оно же типа инкремент и должно само добавить значение).

В итоге получаю такую ошибку:

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) already exists

Вот здесь я не понял, вроде запись с id=1 уже есть, но почему то БД как ьы ее не видит и пытается присвоить новой записи тот же первый номер

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас автоинкремент на данное поле? Покажите DDL таблицы

Comment: А что в самом posrgree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал так:

```
// utils.js
const updateSequence = async (table, column, { queryInterface, transaction }) => {
    const [[{ max }]] = await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`SELECT MAX(${column}) FROM ${table}`, {
        transaction,
    });

    if (!max) return;

    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('${table}', '${column}'), max(${column})) FROM ${table};`,
        { transaction }
    );
};

module.exports = { updateSequence };
```

Seed:

```
const { updateSequence } = require("../utils");

//...

async up (queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert('users', [userdata])

    await updateSequence('users', 'id', { queryInterface });
},
```

**updateSequence**, в принципе, можно использовать в миграции, после описания таблицы:

```
await queryInterface.createTable('users', {
  ...
});

await updateSequence('users', 'id', { queryInterface });
```

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема заключается в "**рассинхронизации первичных ключей в Postgres**":
"*Postgres обрабатывает автоматическое увеличение немного иначе, чем MySQL. В Postgres при создании serial поля вы также создаете поле последовательности, которое отслеживает используемый идентификатор. Это поле последовательности будет начинаться со значения 1*.

*Если вы вставляете в таблицу новую запись и не указываете поле id, она будет использовать значение последовательности, а затем увеличивать последовательность*.

*Однако если вы укажете id поле, последовательность не будет использоваться и не будет обновляться*".
(взято отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970743/postgresql-unique-violation-7-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-const)

Используя следующий скрипт можно пофиксить данную проблему:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users', 'id'), max(id)) FROM users;
```

После этого, последовательность используется в обычном порядке, т.е. инкремент работает как обычно.
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync)

Вот как реализовал в seed:

```
async up (queryInterface) {
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert('users', [userdata])

    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        `SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users', 'id'), max(id)) FROM users;`,
        {type: queryInterface.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}
    );
}
```

Будет интересно почитать комментарии более лучшего решения

Comment: а вам обязательно явно назначать id пользователя в сидах?

Comment: По пользователю не принципиально. Но в проекте есть таблицы, где также сидами добавляются данные. И вот id-шники этих данных уже приницпиальны (имеются связи с этими id в других таблицах). И, т.о., повторилась бы эта "история" - при попытке добавить новую запись, мы получим ошибку "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" . И длилась бы эта ошибка ровно до того момента, пока "расинхронизация первичного ключа" не дошла бы до id последней записи. Если предположить (гипотетически), что записей из сида было бы пару тысящ, то становится совсем печально :)

Comment: обычно такую ситуацию обходят гораздо более изящным способом, чем тот программизм, что написан в ответе. вы создаёте секвенс для заполнения поля таблицы и при создании указываете, что начальное значение секвенса равно 20000, к примеру. и вуаля, у вас 20 тысяч служебных идентификаторов, а записи, создаваемые через апи, получают идентификатором следующее значение секвенса

Comment: пример чего? вот что гуглится в sequelize для управления начальным значением секвенса: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69146674/4496422 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67145333/4496422

Comment: Set the initial AUTO_INCREMENT value for the table in MySQL

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/679
Речь шла о проблеме в Postgres

Comment: я не использую sequelize, так что не мог учесть это. но вы же можете написать миграцию с `ALTER SEQUENCE user_id_seq START / RESTART WITH 20000;`?

Comment: в проекте нет миграций, только сиды